# Remove rows from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need to remove rows from a DataTable dt where a column have a specific value.
Before I remove them I copy them to a other DataTable dt2nd.

It looks like this

```
        for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

            if (row["Column2"].ToString() == "This Value")
            {
                dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
                dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
            }
            if (row["Column2"].ToString() == "Other Value")
            {
                dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
                dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
            }
            //This continues with more if
        }
```

But I get a error message

> "Additional information: This row has been removed from a table and
>   does not have any data.  BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data
>   in this row.".

Lots of rows can have the "This Value" or "Other Value".

The ==" " values can be a lot of different values so if I do it like this it will be a lot of IF statements.

Is there any good way to do this, with LINQ or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

```
        var checkValues = new string[]  { "Some value1", "Some value3" };
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
        dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"Some value1", "Some value2", "Some value3" });
        dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (checkValues.Contains(x["Column1"]))
                {
                    dt1.ImportRow(x);
                    dt.Rows.Remove(x);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This looks good, but is there anyway to solve the fact that I have like 40+ different "Some Value1" I need to check. Like is it possible to put all the values I need to check in a array or something?

Answer (score 1):

This code will work :

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

        if (row["Column2"].ToString() == "This Value")
        {
            dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
            dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
            continue;
        }
        if (row["Column2"].ToString() == "Other Value")
        {
            dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
            dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
            continue; 
        }
        //This continues with more if
    }
```

or you can use a switch statement instead of all the ifs or use else if

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

        if (row["Column2"].ToString() == "This Value")
        {
            dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
            dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
        }
        else if (row["Column2"].ToString() == "Other Value")
        {
            dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
            dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
        }
        //This continues with more else if
    }
```

or

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

        switch(row["Column2"].ToString()){
        case "This Value":
        {
            dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
            dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
            break;
        }
        case "Other Value":
        {
            dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
            dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
            break; 
        }
        //This continues with more case
    }
```

But you can also use a select on your datatable and iflter out all the rows that need to be moved out. something like this :

```
dt.select("Column2 == 'This value' or ...");
```

it will return the rows that satisfy the condition. See example here :
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select

But the code can be made a lot shorter if the action is always the same :

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

        if (
               (row["Column2"].ToString() == "This Value") ||
               (row["Column2"].ToString() == "Other Value") //more checks
           )
        {
            dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
            dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
        }
    }
```

or

```
for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

    switch(row["Column2"].ToString()){
    case "This Value":
    case "Other Value": //more case values
    {
        dt2nd.ImportRow(row); //Copy
        dt.Rows.Remove(row); //Remove
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Frankly, this code will work **only** if there is no logic in this loop *after* all these "if"s. It is not clear from original question - is it so or not.

Comment: The user did post '//This continues with more if ' so this is clear enough to me.

Comment: Nice, yea the problem is that the =="Values" I need to check against is like 40+ different values. And many rows or no rows can have that column value. So I guess I can use something like this or if I could do the == check vs a array that have all the values I need to check against or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var valuesToBeChecked = new String[] { "value1", "value2" };
        var x = from y in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where valuesToBeChecked.Any(t => valuesToBeChecked.Contains(y["Column2"].ToString()))
                select y;
        var z = dt.AsEnumerable().Except(x);
```

Then, you can copy `z` to `datatable` you want:

```
DataTable dt2 = z.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Ok, and how do I remove x from dt?

Comment: To remove I tried foreach (var row in z) dt.Rows.Remove(row); but it didnt work.